# Is there a way to have keep an object centered on hover but not using transforms?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to keep an element centered when it grows or shrinks in size when it is hovered over but **NOT** using transforms or transform origins.

```css
#Group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 220px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(247,247,247,1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(112,112,112,1);
  overflow: visible;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#Group:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
  
#Rectangle_1 {
  fill: rgba(247,247,247,1);
  stroke: rgba(118,118,118,1);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#Rectangle_1:hover {
  fill: rgba(63,181,72,1);
  stroke: rgba(57,57,57,1);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.Rectangle_1:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.361));
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transform-origin:  center;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Rectangle_1">
  <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
</svg>
  
<div id="Group">
</div>
```

Notice that it grows down and to the right and not from the center.

Comment: Why don't you wan to use transform?

Comment: Limitation of the environment

Comment: update the left/top value to rectify the position

Comment: @TemaniAfif i was looking for a CSS property. this seems to work...

Answer (score 0):

It seems I will have to calculate the new left and top position (suggestion by @TemaniAfif). This seems to work ...for now.

```css
#Group {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 220px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(247,247,247,1);
  border: 1px solid rgba(112,112,112,1);
  overflow: visible;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#Group:hover {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 195px;
}
  
#Rectangle_1 {
  fill: rgba(247,247,247,1);
  stroke: rgba(118,118,118,1);
  stroke-width: 1px;
  stroke-linejoin: miter;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  stroke-miterlimit: 4;
  shape-rendering: auto;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

#Rectangle_1:hover {
  fill: rgba(63,181,72,1);
  stroke: rgba(57,57,57,1);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 75px;
  top: 75px;
}

.Rectangle_1 {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  transition: all .3s ease-out;
}

.Rectangle_1:hover {
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.361));
  overflow: visible;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 75px;
  left: 75px;
  transform-origin:  center;
}
```

```html
<svg class="Rectangle_1">
  <rect id="Rectangle_1" rx="0" ry="0" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50">
</svg>
  
<div id="Group">
</div>
```